# Discussion about Taylor expansion

Tags: differentiation, mathematics, calculus

I have a function like

$$\mathcal{F}(\phi_{e}(r),\phi_{c}(r),\phi_{a}(r)) = \exp\left({-\beta\left(\phi_{e}(r) + \phi_{c}(r)\cos{\theta}+\phi_{a}(r)\sin{\theta}\right)}\right).$$

If we assume $\beta\phi_{e} << 1$, $\beta\phi_{c}(r) << 1$, and $\beta\phi_{a}(r)<<1$, can we discuss about expanding the function $\mathcal{F}$? My approach is just expanding the exponents like

$\mathcal{F}(\phi_{e}(r),\phi_{c}(r),\phi_{a}(r)) = 1 -\beta\left(\phi_{e}(r) + \phi_{c}(r)\cos{\theta} + \phi_{a}\sin{\theta}\right)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To first order, your approach is perfect. For higher orders, you may want to do the expansion more carefully since there are cross terms:
$$\mathcal{F}(\phi_e,\phi_c,\phi_a)=e^{-\beta\phi_e}e^{-\beta\phi_c\cos{\theta}}e^{-\beta\phi_a\sin{\theta}}$$
$$=(1-\beta\phi_e+\dotsb)(1-\beta\phi_c\cos{\theta}+\dotsb)(1-\beta\phi_a\sin{\theta}+\dotsb)$$

Comment: Since $\beta\phi_{e}, \beta\phi_{a}, \beta\phi_{c} << 1$, can I discard the crossing terms?

Comment: depending on the level of accuracy you want / the complexity of the phenomena you want to describe. sometimes expanding to linear order is sufficient and sometimes not. it all depends on the problem and your desired form of output